# How to stop Grunt

Tags: node.js, windows-7, gruntjs

This question may be obvious to some, but I searched all over the internet and couldn't find the answer. I was following an install guide on Strut. How do I stop the Grunt task? I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, but it doesn't have a background process?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- If it's a task that you currently running you can stop it with `ctrl + c`
- If it's a task that is running in background you can find his process id (pid) with `ps aux | grep grunt` and then kill it with `kill {pid}`

Comment: `netstat -bo` and `taskkill /PID {pid}` for Windows 7. Thanks, I solved it with `ctrl+c`. There was no background process.

Comment: I had to use `kill -9 {pid}` as my grunt task was caught in an infinite loop

Answer (score 10):

One liner to kill the currently running grunt task:

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep grunt | awk '{print $2}')
```

Explanation:

**Kill** is the command to end a process

The **-9** option is used to [ensure the process is actually killed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184071/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-9-option-in-the-kill-command) if it's stuck in a loop

**ps -aux** lists the currently running processes

**grep -v "grep"** excludes any lines with the word grep so we don't kill the current grep command that we are running

**grep grunt** just returns the line with grunt

And finally **awk '{print $2}'** returns the number in the second column that is the pid. This is what is passed to kill.

Comment: Is this Windows or Linux?  Doesn't run on my Windows box. "kill" is not recognized as a command

Comment: @StephenR Linux

Comment: kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep grunt | awk '{print $2}')

Answer (score 3):

A shorter solution with a nifty trick like Felix Eve's:

```
kill -9 $(ps -aux | grep "[g]runt" | awk '{print $2}')
```

The `[]` avoids having the word 'grunt' in the grep, so it won't get accidentally deleted.

Comment: I used to do things like the above. The natural next step is to stick it into a shell function that you can run more easily. That leads to the bothersome behavior where `grunt` is no longer running, and you get an error from issuing `kill -9` without a pid. I've switched to doing this instead: `ps -aux | grep '[g]runt' | awk '{print $2}' | tee >(xargs -I {} kill -9 {})`. This has the benefit of showing me a PID when something gets killed, and not showing a pid when nothing gets killed - so it's nice visual feedback.

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell, run the [Get-Process cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-5.1), to list all processes, or with a comma-separated list to filter (wildcards work too). Its alias is `ps`. For example:

```
Get-Process grunt, node
```

or

```
ps grunt, node
```

Once you determine the process ID (third column from the right, 'Id'), then you can use [Stop-Process](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177004.aspx) to end it. Its alias is `kill`. For example:

```
Stop-Process 2570
```

or

```
kill 2570
```

I'm posting this because the question and a commenter asks for a Windows, and `grep` doesn't work on my Windows 10 install, and its Powershell equivalent, [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1), doesn't satisfactorily return the full process information. Luckily Get-Process has its own filtering!